# How to send a request to IMAP using ajax in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, imap

I want to use IMAP in a chrome extension. I tried to send it via ajax in background.js but I got this ERROR from chrome extension:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'imaps://XXXX.com/INBOX;UID=1;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE%20FROM%20TO%20SUBJECT)'
> from origin 'chrome-extension://SSSS' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
> data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

In the manifest.json I set some permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/",
    "http://*/",
    ...
]
```

AND this is my ajax call:

$.ajax({

```
type: "POST",
url: "imaps://XXXX.com/INBOX;UID=1;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE%20FROM%20TO%20SUBJECT)",
data: "MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD",
sucess: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
}
```

});

Comment: I seriously doubt the imap scheme is supported by browsers.

Comment: There's no way. All you can do is open this URL in a new tab/window.